# How to install Wifi dervers Realtek RTL8723BE/RTL8188EE 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Drivers in cent os 7

Tags: centos7, wifi, drivers

i was using **Realtek RTL8723BE/RTL8188EE 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Drivers**
when I was using windows but after centos installation, my wifi adapter is not showing please anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the driver from the Realtek website:

http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=21&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false

2. Extract the files from the .zip package
3. Install the necessary dependencies by running the following commands:

sudo yum install gcc
sudo yum install make

4. Change directory to the extracted driver directory

cd /path/to/extracted/driver

5. Compile the driver by running the following command:

make all

6. Install the driver by running the following command:

sudo make install

7. Load the driver by running the following command:

sudo modprobe rtl8723be

8. Reboot your system to have the driver take effect.